# If i open nrrd file using vtk, only black screen is output

Tags: python, vtk

I want to open two nrrd files and then overlap these two files. The first step in this step is to open the nrrd file using vtk's vktImageData or Mapper. I wrote the code to do this, but only black screen appears when I run it.

I've already done this by replacing the Image with a volume and printing the two files over and over. However, when I tried to do color mapping on this result, I noticed that the coordinates of the color mapping did not match the coordinates of the two files. At this time, I did not use the same mapper that rendered the object and the mapper of the color mapping, and I thought that the coordinates were different.

So I start from the beginning to use the same mapper that renders both files and color mapping.

```
import vtk


def main():
    renWin = vtk.vtkRenderWindow()
    renderer = vtk.vtkRenderer()
    renWin.AddRenderer(renderer)
    iren = vtk.vtkRenderWindowInteractor()
    iren.SetRenderWindow(renWin)


    reader = vtk.vtkNrrdReader()
    reader.SetFileName('Segmentation-label_2.nrrd')
    reader.Update()

    mapper = vtk.vtkPolyDataMapper()
    mapper.SetInputConnection(reader.GetOutputPort())

    actor = vtk.vtkActor()
    actor.SetMapper(mapper)

    renderer.AddActor(actor)

    iren.Initialize()
    renWin.Render()
    iren.Start()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

When I run this code, only black screen is output. I have searched a lot of data, but I do not know what the problem is.

I would appreciate your reply.

Comment: NRRD is 3D image data right? unless it is a polydata it won't be displayed by a PolyDataMapper.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yes NRRD is 3D image Data. Because the dimensions in the header file are 3D, and I created this nrrd file myself.

Comment: I think you're not using the right mapper - a quick adjust using https://github.com/Kitware/VTK/blob/master/Examples/ImageProcessing/Python/ImageSlicing.py should get you a minimal working example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By adjusting the example given in https://vtk.org/Wiki/VTK/Examples/Python/DataManipulation/Cube.py this should load your 3D image data with a 2D slice that you move through.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import vtk

# Start by loading some data.
reader = vtk.vtkNrrdReader()
reader.SetFileName('Segmentation-label_2.nrrd')
reader.Update()    

# Calculate the center of the volume
reader.Update()
(xMin, xMax, yMin, yMax, zMin, zMax) = reader.GetExecutive().GetWholeExtent(reader.GetOutputInformation(0))
(xSpacing, ySpacing, zSpacing) = reader.GetOutput().GetSpacing()
(x0, y0, z0) = reader.GetOutput().GetOrigin()

center = [x0 + xSpacing * 0.5 * (xMin + xMax),
          y0 + ySpacing * 0.5 * (yMin + yMax),
          z0 + zSpacing * 0.5 * (zMin + zMax)]

# Matrices for axial, coronal, sagittal, oblique view orientations
axial = vtk.vtkMatrix4x4()
axial.DeepCopy((1, 0, 0, center[0],
                0, 1, 0, center[1],
                0, 0, 1, center[2],
                0, 0, 0, 1))

coronal = vtk.vtkMatrix4x4()
coronal.DeepCopy((1, 0, 0, center[0],
                  0, 0, 1, center[1],
                  0,-1, 0, center[2],
                  0, 0, 0, 1))

sagittal = vtk.vtkMatrix4x4()
sagittal.DeepCopy((0, 0,-1, center[0],
                   1, 0, 0, center[1],
                   0,-1, 0, center[2],
                   0, 0, 0, 1))

oblique = vtk.vtkMatrix4x4()
oblique.DeepCopy((1, 0, 0, center[0],
                  0, 0.866025, -0.5, center[1],
                  0, 0.5, 0.866025, center[2],
                  0, 0, 0, 1))

# Extract a slice in the desired orientation
reslice = vtk.vtkImageReslice()
reslice.SetInputConnection(reader.GetOutputPort())
reslice.SetOutputDimensionality(2)
reslice.SetResliceAxes(sagittal)
reslice.SetInterpolationModeToLinear()

# Create a greyscale lookup table
table = vtk.vtkLookupTable()
table.SetRange(0, 2000) # image intensity range
table.SetValueRange(0.0, 1.0) # from black to white
table.SetSaturationRange(0.0, 0.0) # no color saturation
table.SetRampToLinear()
table.Build()

# Map the image through the lookup table
color = vtk.vtkImageMapToColors()
color.SetLookupTable(table)
color.SetInputConnection(reslice.GetOutputPort())

# Display the image
actor = vtk.vtkImageActor()
actor.GetMapper().SetInputConnection(color.GetOutputPort())

renderer = vtk.vtkRenderer()
renderer.AddActor(actor)

window = vtk.vtkRenderWindow()
window.AddRenderer(renderer)

# Set up the interaction
interactorStyle = vtk.vtkInteractorStyleImage()
interactor = vtk.vtkRenderWindowInteractor()
interactor.SetInteractorStyle(interactorStyle)
window.SetInteractor(interactor)
window.Render()

# Create callbacks for slicing the image
actions = {}
actions["Slicing"] = 0

def ButtonCallback(obj, event):
    if event == "LeftButtonPressEvent":
        actions["Slicing"] = 1
    else:
        actions["Slicing"] = 0

def MouseMoveCallback(obj, event):
    (lastX, lastY) = interactor.GetLastEventPosition()
    (mouseX, mouseY) = interactor.GetEventPosition()
    if actions["Slicing"] == 1:
        deltaY = mouseY - lastY
        reslice.Update()
        sliceSpacing = reslice.GetOutput().GetSpacing()[2]
        matrix = reslice.GetResliceAxes()
        # move the center point that we are slicing through
        center = matrix.MultiplyPoint((0, 0, sliceSpacing*deltaY, 1))
        matrix.SetElement(0, 3, center[0])
        matrix.SetElement(1, 3, center[1])
        matrix.SetElement(2, 3, center[2])
        window.Render()
    else:
        interactorStyle.OnMouseMove()


interactorStyle.AddObserver("MouseMoveEvent", MouseMoveCallback)
interactorStyle.AddObserver("LeftButtonPressEvent", ButtonCallback)
interactorStyle.AddObserver("LeftButtonReleaseEvent", ButtonCallback)

# Start interaction
interactor.Start()
del renderer
del window
del interactor
```

Comment: Thanks your reply. but this code also i see only black screen

Comment: what is your intensity range of your data? VTK doesn't understand and won't do it automatically - you have to provide it the upper and lower bounds. table.SetRange(0, 2000) # image intensity range -- is the assumption at the moment

Comment: When I change intensity Range, the screen is displayed. Really Thanks! But i will change this code. Because my purpose is displayed 3D Data.

Comment: best of luck - if you add in other vtkImageReslice objects using the coronal, axial reslice axes this should provide you the 3D functionality you are looking for.